# Track changes of multiple rows as one revision in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, revisionable

I want to track changes in laravel 5.3 using sofa/revisionable package (or any other package which performs same action)

Tables are as follows:

```
item
    id - primary key
    title - text

item_fields
    id - primary key
    title - name of the field

item_field_values
    item_id - foreign key to item(id)
    field_id - foreign key to item_fields(id)
    value - text
```

Example

```
item
   1 - "John"

item_fields
   1 - "email"
   2 - "last login time"
   3 - "balance"

item_values
   1 - 1 - "john@example.com" // email
   1 - 2 - "01.11.2016 11:30:03" // last login time
   1 - 3 - "$38" // balance
```

For example, user's balance changes at the same time as user's logon, so revisions table would contain something like this

```
 "For user 1 last login time changed from 01.11.2016 11:30.03 to 02.11.2016 10:20:00"
 "For user 1 balance changed from $38 to $36.50"
```

These are two separate fields, not related to each other. If I want to show them as `one change`, but not different changes, I can not make this, because these fields have no links to each other.

Another example, new row is added to revisions table

```
 "For user 1 balance changed from $36.5 to $33"
```

It is one diff.

How can I select related changes from different fields as one bulk revision? There will be lots of item_fields (hundreds). I can not rely on `created` time of rows in `revisions` table.

Problem with all revisions related packages in laravel is that they track changes to all fields in one model, but in my case there is one model (item_field_values), but one revision/version can contain many changed rows.

Comment: There's a good [package](https://github.com/mpociot/versionable) available.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not answer my question.